# Best way to load XML attributes to dataset c#

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset, load

what is best way to load such a XML file into a dataset/datatable. The xml file hast the node "fields" which define the fields (columns) of a table. The "rows" represent the rows of this table. Each table row of a table as an id. Furthermore I have got the field "test1id" which contain the id of the row of table "test1" (FK).

I allready tried the xdocument.load function, but that does not work with these xml scheme. Do I have to parse the document manually with xmldocument for example or does exist a smarter solution? I would be great if the PK, FK will be set also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xmldocdata>
<tiopf version="2.1"/>
 <tables>
  <table table_name="test1">
   <fields>
    <field field_Size="40" field_kind="string" field_name="id"/>
    <field field_Size="40" field_kind="string" field_name="name"/>
   </fields>
   <rows>
    <row name="Chris" id="882AEC07-6BB7-4160-802C-517CEC222402"/>
   </rows>
 </table>
  <table table_name="test2">
   <fields>
    <field field_Size="40" field_kind="string" field_name="id"/>
    <field field_Size="40" field_kind="string" field_name="documentver"/>
    <field field_Size="40" field_kind="string" field_name="test1id"/>
   </fields>
   <rows>
    <row documentationversion="1" id="B18752A3-7AFF-4575-89C1-23B5F9F6AA3B" test1id="882AEC07-6BB7-4160-802C-517CEC222402"/>
    <row documentationver="1" id="B18752A3-7AFF-4575-89C1-23B5F9F6AA3C" test1id="882AEC07-6BB7-4160-802C-517CEC222402"/>
   </rows>
  </table>
 </tables>
```

Comment: Try the Data library method  DataSet.ReadXml(filename).  Code : DataSet ds = new DataSet(); ds.ReadXml(filename);